# replace characters after match

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file that contains lines of commands, some with slashes. I need the slashes in most fields for the commands to work, but not in one, specifically not in the last column, where I'm outputting to a file. I'd like to replace the slashes in the last column with hyphens.

I've tried looking for awk and sed suggestions with back references but haven't come across something that works.

I have a file with lines like:

```
foo find "https://localhost" "/website/foo" "this/that/the/other" "yes/no/maybe" -u admin -p admin > yes/no/maybe.txt
```

I'd like to replace the slashes in the last column with hyphens, like this:

```
foo find "https://localhost" "/website/foo" "this/that/the/other" "yes/no/maybe" -u admin -p admin > yes-no-maybe.txt
```

without affecting the other columns where I have slashes.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to ask about programming problems, i.e. the obstacles you encounter while programming. Describing what you need and expecting a solution is not how this community is meant to be used. Please show what you have tried and describe in which way it failed to work as expected.

Comment: Without describing the specific problem you encounter, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in `NF` variable contains the number of fields in the current record, which allows you to operate on the last field without having to know how many fields there are. That makes it as simple as:

```
$ awk '{gsub("/","-",$NF)}1' file
foo find "https://localhost" "/website/foo" "this/that/the/other" "yes/no/maybe" -u admin -p admin > yes-no-maybe.txt
```

Comment: i agree with @Yunnosch but the query can be written more efficiently like this: awk 'gsub("/","-",$NF)' file

Comment: Thanks for adding an explanation.

Comment: @yoga, be careful with that style of query. If the last field doesn't have any "/" characters, `gsub` will return 0 and the line won't be printed. (Try it with a line like `foo find ... > bar.txt`)

Comment: interesting to know this. Thanks jas